# No se ingresan los datos a la DB

Tags: php, base-de-datos

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion y estoy realizando un proyecto. Estoy trabajando con base de datos, active record y tableplus. el problema es que cuando quiero ingresar los valores a la base de datos, no se agregan. No es error de table plus ya que cuando chequeo la db desde powershell no se muestra nada. Ni usuarios, ni password, ni email, nada. Simplemente no se agregan.Me confunde mucho porque como dije no popea error alguno, supongo que sera algo de codigo que haya insertado mal en la db pero en el tutorial que sigo el codigo es el mismo. Adjunto codigo:

```
//Conectarse a la DB
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'appsalon_mvc';

$db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$db) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL.";
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
?>
```

```
//Creando tabla, columnas, y variables para asignarlas en la Base de Datos
<?php
namespace Model;
class Usuario extends ActiveRecord{
    //Base de datos
    protected static $tabla = 'usuarios';
    protected static $columnaDB = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'password', 'telefono', 'admin', 'confirmado', 'token'];

    //crear atributos para los datos de la columna

    public $id;
    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $telefono;
    public $admin;
    public $confirmado;
    public $token;

    //Definir constructor

    public function __construct($args = []){
        $this->id = $args['id'] ?? null;
        $this->nombre = $args['nombre'] ?? '';
        $this->apellido = $args['apellido'] ?? '';
        $this->password = $args['password'] ?? '';
        $this->telefono = $args['telefono'] ?? '';
        $this->admin = $args['admin'] ?? '0';
        $this->confirmado = $args['confirmado'] ?? '0';
        $this->token = $args['token'] ?? '';
    }
```

Comment: Saludos @dissmis3d. Creo que a tu pregunta le hace falta algo más de contexto, ya que no veo donde ejecutas una sentencia SQL para insertar los usuarios en tu base de datos.

Comment: Podrías intentar usar un `try` para ver si así te arroja un error

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la sentencia para insertar usuarios

```
public function crear() {
        // Sanitizar los datos
        $atributos = $this->sanitizarAtributos();

        // Insertar en la base de datos
        $query = " INSERT INTO " . static::$tabla . " ( ";
        $query .= join(', ', array_keys($atributos));
        $query .= " ) VALUES (' "; 
        $query .= join("', '", array_values($atributos));
        $query .= " ') ";

        // Resultado de la consulta
        $resultado = self::$db->query($query);
        return [
           'resultado' =>  $resultado,
           'id' => self::$db->insert_id
        ];
    }
```

La funcion crear luego la llamo para el controlador de Active Record que muestra la vista:

```
class LoginController{
    public static function login(Router $router){
       $router->render('auth/login');
    }

    public static function logout(){
        echo 'desde logout';
    }

    public static function olvide(Router $router){
        $router->render('auth/olvide-password',[
            
        ]);
    }

    public static function recuperar(){
        echo 'desde recuperar';
    }
    public static function crear(Router $router){
        $usuario = new Usuario;
        //alertas vacias
        $alertas = [];
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
            
            $usuario->sincronizar($_POST);
            $alertas = $usuario->validarNuevaCuenta();

            //revisar que alertas este vacio

            if(empty($alertas)){
                //verificar que el usuario no este registrado
                $resultado = $usuario->existeUsuario();

                if($resultado->num_rows){
                    $alertas = Usuario::getAlertas();
                }else{
                    //Hashear password
                    $usuario->hashPassword();
                    //Generar un token unico
                    $usuario->crearToken();
                    //Enviar el email
                    $email = new Email($usuario->nombre, $usuario->email, $usuario->token);

                    $email->enviarConfirmacion();

                    //Crear el usuario
                    $resultado = $usuario->guardar();
                    if($resultado){
                        header('Location: /mensaje');
                    }

                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).